# Overtone and sound-in on Mac

Tags: macos, clojure, supercollider, overtone

I am trying to call `(sound-in 0)` (I have tried all values 0-7) and I get a large edn response but no audio is returned. Not really sure where to look.

The following is the mentioned edn response. I'm confused because I'm not getting any error, so i think this is an issue with audio devices and ports. I've messed around with Jack and creating Aggregate Devices but with no luck.

This comes from running

```
(definst mic [] (sound-in 0))
(mic)
```

The edn is too long so I've included a link externally. https://pastebin.com/f9CqqZSc

The following is a more reasonable length response

```
(definst mic [] (in 8))
(mic)
```

```
{:synth "learn-leipzig.audio-visual/mic",
 :id 42,
 :target 39,
 :position :tail,
 :args {},
 :sdef
 {:name "learn-leipzig.audio-visual/mic",
  :constants [8.0 18.0],
  :params (),
  :pnames (),
  :ugens
  ({:id 315,
    :name "In",
    :rate 2,
    :rate-name :ar,
    :special 0,
    :args (8.0),
    :n-outputs 1,
    :spec
    {:args
     ({:doc "the index of the bus to read in from",
       :name "bus",
       :default 0,
       :expands? true}
      {:doc
       "the number of channels (i.e. adjacent buses) to\n                     read in. The default is 1. You cannot modulate this\n                     number by assigning it to an argument in a\n                     SynthDef.",
       :name "num-channels",
       :default 1,
       :mode :num-outs,
       :expands? false}),
     :fn-names {"in:ar" :ar, "in:kr" :kr, "in" :ar},
     :init #function[overtone.sc.machinery.ugen.specs/with-init-fn/fn--4096],
     :full-doc
     "\n  Read a signal from a bus. \n\n  [bus 0, num-channels 1]\n\n  bus          - The index of the bus to read in \n                 from \n  num-channels - The number of channels (i.e. \n                 adjacent buses) to read in. The \n                 default is 1. You cannot modulate \n                 this number by assigning it to an \n                 argument in a SynthDef. \n\n  In:kr is functionally similar to in-feedback. That is it \n  reads all data on the bus whether it is from the current \n  cycle or not. This allows for it to receive data from \n  later in the node order.\n\n  in:ar reads only data from the current cycle, and will \n  zero data from earlier cycles (for use within that synth; \n  the data remains on the bus). Because of this and the fact \n  that the various out ugens mix their output with data from \n  the current cycle but overwrite data from an earlier cycle \n  it may be necessary to use a private control bus when this \n  type of feedback is desired. \n\n  Categories: \n  Rates: [ :ar, :kr ]\n  Default rate: :ar",
     :name "In",
     :default-rate :ar,
     :summary "Read a signal from a bus.",
     :categories [],
     :rates #{:ar :kr},
     :doc
     "in:kr is functionally similar to in-feedback. That is it\n             reads all data on the bus whether it is from the current\n             cycle or not. This allows for it to receive data from later\n             in the node order.\n\n             in:ar reads only data from the current cycle, and will zero\n             data from earlier cycles (for use within that synth; the\n             data remains on the bus). Because of this and the fact that\n             the various out ugens mix their output with data from the\n             current cycle but overwrite data from an earlier cycle it\n             may be necessary to use a private control bus when this\n             type of feedback is desired."},
    :arg-map {:bus 8, :num-channels 1},
    :orig-args (8),
    :outputs ({:rate 2}),
    :inputs ({:src -1, :index 0})}
   {:id 316,
    :name "Out",
    :rate 2,
    :rate-name :ar,
    :special 0,
    :args
    (18.0
     {:id 315,
      :name "In",
      :rate 2,
      :rate-name :ar,
      :special 0,
      :args (8.0),
      :n-outputs 1,
      :spec
      {:args
       ({:doc "the index of the bus to read in from",
         :name "bus",
         :default 0,
         :expands? true}
        {:doc
         "the number of channels (i.e. adjacent buses) to\n                     read in. The default is 1. You cannot modulate this\n                     number by assigning it to an argument in a\n                     SynthDef.",
         :name "num-channels",
         :default 1,
         :mode :num-outs,
         :expands? false}),
       :fn-names {"in:ar" :ar, "in:kr" :kr, "in" :ar},
       :init #function[overtone.sc.machinery.ugen.specs/with-init-fn/fn--4096],
       :full-doc
       "\n  Read a signal from a bus. \n\n  [bus 0, num-channels 1]\n\n  bus          - The index of the bus to read in \n                 from \n  num-channels - The number of channels (i.e. \n                 adjacent buses) to read in. The \n                 default is 1. You cannot modulate \n                 this number by assigning it to an \n                 argument in a SynthDef. \n\n  In:kr is functionally similar to in-feedback. That is it \n  reads all data on the bus whether it is from the current \n  cycle or not. This allows for it to receive data from \n  later in the node order.\n\n  in:ar reads only data from the current cycle, and will \n  zero data from earlier cycles (for use within that synth; \n  the data remains on the bus). Because of this and the fact \n  that the various out ugens mix their output with data from \n  the current cycle but overwrite data from an earlier cycle \n  it may be necessary to use a private control bus when this \n  type of feedback is desired. \n\n  Categories: \n  Rates: [ :ar, :kr ]\n  Default rate: :ar",
       :name "In",
       :default-rate :ar,
       :summary "Read a signal from a bus.",
       :categories [],
       :rates #{:ar :kr},
       :doc
       "in:kr is functionally similar to in-feedback. That is it\n             reads all data on the bus whether it is from the current\n             cycle or not. This allows for it to receive data from later\n             in the node order.\n\n             in:ar reads only data from the current cycle, and will zero\n             data from earlier cycles (for use within that synth; the\n             data remains on the bus). Because of this and the fact that\n             the various out ugens mix their output with data from the\n             current cycle but overwrite data from an earlier cycle it\n             may be necessary to use a private control bus when this\n             type of feedback is desired."},
      :arg-map {:bus 8, :num-channels 1},
      :orig-args (8)}),
    :n-outputs 0,
    :spec
    {:args
     ({:doc
       "the index of the buss to write to. The lowest index\n                     numbers are written to the audio hardware.",
       :name "bus",
       :expands? true}
      {:doc
       "a list of signals or single output to write\n                     out. You cannot change the size of this once a\n                     synth has been defined.",
       :name "signals",
       :mode :append-sequence,
       :expands? false}),
     :fn-names {"out:ar" :ar, "out:kr" :kr, "out" :auto},
     :init #function[overtone.sc.machinery.ugen.specs/with-init-fn/fn--4096],
     :full-doc
     "\n  write a signal to a bus, adding to previous contents. \n\n  [bus :none, signals :none]\n\n  bus     - The index of the buss to write to. The \n            lowest index numbers are written to \n            the audio hardware. \n  signals - A list of signals or single output to \n            write out. You cannot change the size \n            of this once a synth has been defined. \n\n  Write a signal to a bus, adding to any existing contents\n\n  N.B. Out is subject to control rate jitter. Where sample \n  accurate output is needed, use OffsetOut.\n\n  When using an array of bus indexes, the channel array will \n  just be copied to each bus index in the array. So (out:ar \n  [bus1 bus2] channels-array) will be the same as (+ (out:ar \n  bus1 channelsArray) (out:ar bus2 channelsArray)). \n\n  Categories: \n  Rates: [ :ar, :kr ]\n  Default rate: :auto",
     :check
     #function[overtone.sc.machinery.ugen.check/mk-when-rate/fn--4319/fn--4320],
     :auto-rate true,
     :name "Out",
     :default-rate :auto,
     :num-outs 0,
     :summary "write a signal to a bus, adding to previous contents.",
     :categories [],
     :rates #{:ar :kr},
     :doc
     "write a signal to a bus, adding to any existing contents\n\n             N.B. Out is subject to control rate jitter. Where sample\n             accurate output is needed, use OffsetOut.\n\n             When using an array of bus indexes, the channel array will\n             just be copied to each bus index in the array. So (out:ar\n             [bus1 bus2] channels-array) will be the same as (+ (out:ar\n             bus1 channelsArray) (out:ar bus2 channelsArray))."},
    :arg-map
    {:bus 18,
     :signals
     {:id 315,
      :name "In",
      :rate 2,
      :rate-name :ar,
      :special 0,
      :args (8.0),
      :n-outputs 1,
      :spec
      {:args
       ({:doc "the index of the bus to read in from",
         :name "bus",
         :default 0,
         :expands? true}
        {:doc
         "the number of channels (i.e. adjacent buses) to\n                     read in. The default is 1. You cannot modulate this\n                     number by assigning it to an argument in a\n                     SynthDef.",
         :name "num-channels",
         :default 1,
         :mode :num-outs,
         :expands? false}),
       :fn-names {"in:ar" :ar, "in:kr" :kr, "in" :ar},
       :init #function[overtone.sc.machinery.ugen.specs/with-init-fn/fn--4096],
       :full-doc
       "\n  Read a signal from a bus. \n\n  [bus 0, num-channels 1]\n\n  bus          - The index of the bus to read in \n                 from \n  num-channels - The number of channels (i.e. \n                 adjacent buses) to read in. The \n                 default is 1. You cannot modulate \n                 this number by assigning it to an \n                 argument in a SynthDef. \n\n  In:kr is functionally similar to in-feedback. That is it \n  reads all data on the bus whether it is from the current \n  cycle or not. This allows for it to receive data from \n  later in the node order.\n\n  in:ar reads only data from the current cycle, and will \n  zero data from earlier cycles (for use within that synth; \n  the data remains on the bus). Because of this and the fact \n  that the various out ugens mix their output with data from \n  the current cycle but overwrite data from an earlier cycle \n  it may be necessary to use a private control bus when this \n  type of feedback is desired. \n\n  Categories: \n  Rates: [ :ar, :kr ]\n  Default rate: :ar",
       :name "In",
       :default-rate :ar,
       :summary "Read a signal from a bus.",
       :categories [],
       :rates #{:ar :kr},
       :doc
       "in:kr is functionally similar to in-feedback. That is it\n             reads all data on the bus whether it is from the current\n             cycle or not. This allows for it to receive data from later\n             in the node order.\n\n             in:ar reads only data from the current cycle, and will zero\n             data from earlier cycles (for use within that synth; the\n             data remains on the bus). Because of this and the fact that\n             the various out ugens mix their output with data from the\n             current cycle but overwrite data from an earlier cycle it\n             may be necessary to use a private control bus when this\n             type of feedback is desired."},
      :arg-map {:bus 8, :num-channels 1},
      :orig-args (8)}},
    :orig-args
    (18
     {:id 315,
      :name "In",
      :rate 2,
      :rate-name :ar,
      :special 0,
      :args (8.0),
      :n-outputs 1,
      :spec
      {:args
       ({:doc "the index of the bus to read in from",
         :name "bus",
         :default 0,
         :expands? true}
        {:doc
         "the number of channels (i.e. adjacent buses) to\n                     read in. The default is 1. You cannot modulate this\n                     number by assigning it to an argument in a\n                     SynthDef.",
         :name "num-channels",
         :default 1,
         :mode :num-outs,
         :expands? false}),
       :fn-names {"in:ar" :ar, "in:kr" :kr, "in" :ar},
       :init #function[overtone.sc.machinery.ugen.specs/with-init-fn/fn--4096],
       :full-doc
       "\n  Read a signal from a bus. \n\n  [bus 0, num-channels 1]\n\n  bus          - The index of the bus to read in \n                 from \n  num-channels - The number of channels (i.e. \n                 adjacent buses) to read in. The \n                 default is 1. You cannot modulate \n                 this number by assigning it to an \n                 argument in a SynthDef. \n\n  In:kr is functionally similar to in-feedback. That is it \n  reads all data on the bus whether it is from the current \n  cycle or not. This allows for it to receive data from \n  later in the node order.\n\n  in:ar reads only data from the current cycle, and will \n  zero data from earlier cycles (for use within that synth; \n  the data remains on the bus). Because of this and the fact \n  that the various out ugens mix their output with data from \n  the current cycle but overwrite data from an earlier cycle \n  it may be necessary to use a private control bus when this \n  type of feedback is desired. \n\n  Categories: \n  Rates: [ :ar, :kr ]\n  Default rate: :ar",
       :name "In",
       :default-rate :ar,
       :summary "Read a signal from a bus.",
       :categories [],
       :rates #{:ar :kr},
       :doc
       "in:kr is functionally similar to in-feedback. That is it\n             reads all data on the bus whether it is from the current\n             cycle or not. This allows for it to receive data from later\n             in the node order.\n\n             in:ar reads only data from the current cycle, and will zero\n             data from earlier cycles (for use within that synth; the\n             data remains on the bus). Because of this and the fact that\n             the various out ugens mix their output with data from the\n             current cycle but overwrite data from an earlier cycle it\n             may be necessary to use a private control bus when this\n             type of feedback is desired."},
      :arg-map {:bus 8, :num-channels 1},
      :orig-args (8)}),
    :outputs (),
    :inputs ({:src -1, :index 1} {:src 0, :index 0})})},
 :status #<Atom@2b513c46: :live>,
 :loaded? #<Promise@64a0d5fc: true>}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the edn response?

Comment: updated @JaredSmith and updated again with a more complete response

Comment: You're out of my depth: `sound-in` is created by a fairly complicated macro `defcgen`. You may have better luck opening a github issue than asking here.